# How to upload 5 million rows in MS SQL in less time using python

Tags: python, sql-server, pymysql

I cleaning up the raw data from the different sources and stored the data in one variable `new_df`
This dataframe have 5million rows that needs to be populated in MS sql. I am currently using `pymysql` but the problem is it taking lot of time for the upload.

I tried dividing the dataframe into the chunks of 5000 but still its taking lot of time to upload.

currently I am using the following code

```
server      = "0.0.0.0"
    user        = "XXXXX"
    password    = "XXXX"
    dbname      = "XXXXX"
    conn = pymssql.connect(server,user,password,dbname)
    cur = conn.cursor()  
    cur.execute ("insert into dbo.DBO values (%s,%s))
   
cur.close()
conn.commit()
```

is there a way that I can push 5 million records within few minutes ? kindly help on this regards,

Note - I am defining function and calling the function on the dataframe.

Comment: Use executemany instead of execute. Maybe you should try ODBC drivers that are faster than pymssql

Comment: You talk about MS SQL and tagged the question with `sql-server`, but using `pymysql`? Ah, I see in the code `pymssql`...

Comment: If you're using pymssql, note that it was also [discontinued back in 2019](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668).

Comment: Tried with executemany and odbc there is no much difference @nacho

Comment: The if discontinued, what is the best way to do@Larnu

Comment: Note discontinue notice advises what you should be using instead, @rqqa .

Comment: The first question you should consider is why you have millions of rows in a dataframe. But a quick search of "python sql server bulk insert" will find many similar discussions - try it.